# How to configure InnoDB/MariaDB to not fill ibdata1 with (rollback/undo?) data that is useless in an in-memory database?

Tags: innodb, mariadb, in-memory-database, ibdata, mvcc

I'm trying to run a tiny (~100-200 MB) database in-memory, but ibdata1 grows out of control.

Situation: MariaDB is running on a resource constrained HW (Raspberry, 1GB RAM), storing non-critical sensory data (like room temperature). The real file system is an SD card, so frequent writes destroy it. Storing data in-memory would be a good option.

What is not a solution:

- Memory storage engine can't handle TEXT columns
- Aria storage engine can't handle foreign keys
- MyRocks storage engine is not available for 32-bit platforms
- SQLite ///:memory: can't handle the "load", throws uncountable 'cannot commit - no transaction is active' errors

What I've tried:

- using tmpfs for datadir and tmpdir
- tweaking InnoDB to minimal resource usage
- disabling doublewrite buffering, disabling change buffering, using READ-UNCOMMITTED isolation

See [configuration](https://github.com/lmagyar/homeassistant-addon-mariadb-inmemory/blob/master/mariadb/rootfs/etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf)

But when I purge old data, the DELETE causes ibdata1 to grow nearly to the 100% size of the table I delete 10-15% of the rows from. My **guess** is that Rollbacks Segments and Undo Tablespace is still very active, but I can't "disable" MVCC altogether.

**How to configure InnoDB/MariaDB to not fill ibdata1 with (rollback/undo?) data that is useless in an in-memory database?**

Comment: No-can-do.  Possibly in MySQL 8.0 the handling of temp tables would avoid some of that.

Comment: There is an option to regularly truncate ibdata1, but nobody seems to know about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72122560/2755656 Sad, that I can't even post it as an answer...

Comment: See this way for better "purging":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Answer (score 2):

Doing smaller transactions and keeping connections not open (Open Transactions) for long time will probably do the job.

And:

The undo log is usually part of the physical system tablespace, but from MariaDB 10.0, the innodb_undo_directory and innodb_undo_tablespaces system variables can be used to split into different tablespaces and store in a different location (perhaps on a different storage device).

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-undo-log/

For MEMORY: What about VARCHAR(65532)?

Comment: I've checked: the connecting SQLAlchemy client deletes data in batches. Finally I gave up. Currently on each start a script "preloads" the DB with a modified schema (no FK), Aria and SQLAlchemy works. InnoDB disabled, exploding ibdata1 eliminated.